# How to Increase REPL font size in intellij idea...?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, clojure-repl

i use intellij 11.1.2 and is there a way to change REPL font size.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the font in the tab `Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Console Font` in IDEA settings.